# Is Valgrind's cachegrind affected by multithreaded code?

Tags: c, profiling, valgrind

If I run Valgrind cachegrind, will the results with one or more threads be different? Or Valgrind just sequentializes the program and only reports the work of one thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valgrind serializes *all* threads in an indeterminate fashion and analyses the sequential code flow. You will receive results about all your code, but the results may not be representative of an actual production run of the same code. (For example, many concurrency-related bugs will not manifest in a program that's run under Valgrind.)

Comment: Thanks. A follow up "yes-no" question before accepting the answer :) Will cachegrind count *all* cache misses (from all threads, instead of just one) and aggregate them?

Comment: @DervinThunk: Yes, what else could it do? But beware that the caching behaviour of the serialized program may differ from the real run. I don't know enough about cachegrind to tell whether that's a significant effect. But since total serialization is a possible execution path on a real machine (e.g. a single-core machine), I imagine that's still useful information.